Allure command not recognized , but version command works
I am trying to use Allure for generating test reports. I have installed Allure and added the bin folder path to the system's environment variables. When I run allure version in the terminal, it works and shows the version correctly. However, when I run any other Allure command, such as allure serve allure-results, I get the following error:
allure : The term 'allure' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
At line:1 char:1
+ allure serve allure-results
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (allure:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Here are the steps I've taken:
Installed Allure.
Verified installation by running allure version, which works.
Added C:\Automation\allure-2.32.0\bin to the system's PATH variable.
Run the followed command:
allure serve allure-results

**What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?
**
I use windows 10
Thank you!
I hope explained myselef.

Use the following code to check the PATH received by the terminal session:
$Env:PATH -split ';'

Allure's binary folder (C:\Automation\allure-2.32.0\bin in your case) should be listed. If that's not the case, check in the following order:

Is the PATH set up correctly? Open the "Environment variables" dialog, double-click "PATH" and check the list of paths here.
Did you restart the terminal? Otherwise, it won't see the updated environment variables. Note that not just a tab but the entire window should be closed and reopened. If you're using an IDE's integrated terminal (like the one in VSCode), restart the IDE.

If nothing helps, you may fix the PATH just for the current session:
$Env:PATH = $Env:PATH + ";C:\Automation\allure-2.32.0\bin"
allure --help

If the PATH is correct, but the error still exists, check if the folder contains allure.bat:
Get-ChildItem C:\Automation\allure-2.32.0\bin

If the file is missing, you should reinstall Allure. If it's in place, well... I don't have more ideas besides executing it by its full name:
$allure = "C:\Automation\allure-2.32.0\bin\allure.bat"
&allure --help

All those complexities are why I prefer installing Allure with scoop.
I hope this helped.
